# Function doesn't read a file when included as a part of a GLUT project

Tags: c++, string, file, project

I have created a function where you input a file and it returns a string with the file content:

**file_to_string.cpp**

```
#include <fstream>
#include "file_to_string.h"

std::string file_to_(const char* name)
{
    std::ifstream in(name);
    std::string output((std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(in)), std::istreambuf_iterator<char>());
    return output;
}
```

When I call this function in the same file it works properly. However, when I execute this file as part of a GLUT project it returns nothing.

These are the rest of the files which the project is made of (I have suppressed superfluous parts of the main file):

**file_to_string.h**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

std::string file_to_(const char* name);
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include <GL/glut.h>
#include "file_to_string.h"

static void CheckShaders (void)
{
   std::cout << file_to_("shader.vs");
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    CheckShaders();

    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGBA);
    glutInitWindowSize(512, 384);
    glutInitWindowPosition(100, 100);
    glutCreateWindow("Program");

    return 0;
}
```

**shader.vs**

```
#version 330

layout (location = 0) in vec3 Position;

void main()
{
    gl_Position = vec4(0.5 * Position.x, 0.5 * Position.y, Position.z, 1.0);
}
```

Comment: So what you're saying is, it "returns nothing" when you run it in a context that you haven't shown us? Anyway, this is almost certainly a relative paths issue....

Comment: You can always test if the file hasn't been open, and then not actually read from it, but maybe throw an error or something.

Comment: This file is included as a part of GLUT project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the problem. It turns out that as "Lightness Races in Orbit" says it is a linking problem. In order for CodeBlocks to recognize a shader file, the file name must contain the full path when the function is called.